# Migrating large user to its own index in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In Shay's Berlin Buzzwords talk, in the "user data flow" portion, he talked about "very large users can be migrated to their own respective indices". Is this said migration a out-of-the-box supported operation with no user-visible disruption, or is it a custom migration that we'll have to implement ourselves?

Comment: Some of us didn't hear the Berlin Buzzwords talk. You haven't specified which environment your referring to, or precisely what you mean by a migration. As such this question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 2):

As Mike W said, we need more information to give you a better answer.

But I think you are trying to migrate that specific user to his own index. If so, we should be using the alias feature elaticsearch gives you out-of-the-box. You can read more of it at this link

http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime/

I believe you need a mapping to support your idea. Mapping each user to the corresponding index, so very large users will go to their own index and others not so large can share the same index.